# Google Analytics Enchanced eCommerce will not record cart activity

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

I implemented enchanced ecommerse tracking on my website. Everything seem to work, except addition of products to shopping cart.
What I did so far:
1. Manually checked that corresponding JS is called and code is correct as far as I can see
2. Used Chrome extension to debug GA. Looks fine to me -- seems that event is being sent

Site in question is www.hatsfromoz.com.au Code will appear on any product page at the bottom of page (function recordCartAction())

Code:

```
function recordCartAction(action, id, name, category, brand, variant, price, qty) {
ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': '\'' + id + '\'',
'name': '\'' + name + '\'',
'category': '\'' + category + '\'',
'brand': '\'' + brand + '\'',
'variant': '\'' + variant + '\'',
'price': '\'' + price + '\'',
'quantity': '\'' + qty + '\''
});
ga('ec:setAction', '\'' + action + '\'');
ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', (action == 'add')? 'add to cart' : 'remove from cart');
}ga('send', 'pageview');
```

"action" can be "add" or "remove".

I use Chrome extension to see GA data and all appear to be OK
Here is a log from Chrome GA debugging extension:

```
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j23d&a=598000483&t=event&_s=2&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hatsfromoz.com.au%2Fcatalog%2Foyster-ladies-winter-fashion-bucket-hats-…Fashion%20Hats'&pr1br='12'&pr1va=''&pr1pr='99.9500'&pr1qt='1'&z=1854191142

analytics_debug.js:9
_j1 (&jid) analytics_debug.js:9
adSenseId (&a) 598000483 analytics_debug.js:9
apiVersion (&v) 1 analytics_debug.js:9
clientId (&cid) 691067355.1407048234 analytics_debug.js:9
ec:action (&pa) 'add' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" brand (&pr1br) '12' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" category (&pr1ca) 'Ladies Winter Fashion Hats' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" id (&pr1id) '2763' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" name (&pr1nm) 'Oyster Ladies winter fashion bucket hats Fillies Collection F501O' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" price (&pr1pr) '99.9500' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" quantity (&pr1qt) '1' analytics_debug.js:9
ec:product "1" variant (&pr1va) '' analytics_debug.js:9
encoding (&de) UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:9
eventAction (&ea) click analytics_debug.js:9
eventCategory (&ec) UX analytics_debug.js:9
eventLabel (&el) add to cart analytics_debug.js:9
flashVersion (&fl) 14.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:9
hitType (&t) event analytics_debug.js:9
javaEnabled (&je) 1 analytics_debug.js:9
language (&ul) en-us analytics_debug.js:9
location (&dl) http://www.hatsfromoz.com.au/catalog/oyster-ladies-winter-fashion-bucket-hats-fillies-collection-f501o-p-2763.html analytics_debug.js:9
screenColors (&sd) 24-bit analytics_debug.js:9
screenResolution (&sr) 1920x1200 analytics_debug.js:9
title (&dt) Oyster ladies winter fashion bucket hats buy online in Australia analytics_debug.js:9
trackingId (&tid) UA-XXXXXXXXX-1 analytics_debug.js:9
viewportSize (&vp) 1620x1005 analytics_debug.js:9
```

Any ideas why shopping cart events are not recording?

Thanks,
Rudolf

Comment: any chances a view filter is applied? or data processing delay? everything seems to be correctly implemented and I can't seea reason for this not to work...

Comment: I managed to get through to Google support.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get through to Google support.

They finally verified that my code is, indeed, OK and problem seem to be on their side. At the moment it was passed to Google Engineering team for further investigations.

Rudolf
P.S. Anyone needs a good test engineer? Just in one week I found bug in Google and in eBay :-)